# How to get credit card details from in plain text while using Authorize.Net API getCustomerProfileRequest?

Tags: authorize.net, credit-card

I am trying to get the `creditcardNumber` which is being sent by Authorize.Net API while calling `getCustomerProfileRequest` in the form of `XXX411`. I want to read the actual `cardNumber`.

I am using `response.profile.paymentProfiles(0).payment.Item.cardNumber.ToString()`

This is returning masked value.

Answer (score 2):

A customer profile can be used for payment transactions, just change the payment object to [Charge a Customer Profile](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-customer-profile).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the full card number back from Authorize.Net. The purpose of creating the payment profile is so you never have to deal with the credit card number once it is created thus reducing your PCI compliance scope and level of risk as well as offer a level of convenience to you when making payments against that credit card. There is no need to get the card number back as you have no reason to have it.

Comment: I am storing the card details for each customer, and when the customer chooses one of the cards, I need cardNumber and expiration date to successfully carry out the transaction. And suggestions how to tackle this scenario

Comment: Your using the authorize.net api incorrectly. You don't need the card information to make a charge. You just use the payment profile ID to make the charge. That's what it's there for.